# Windows CE 6 remote debugging. No call stack when pause program

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-ce, remote-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for a remote debugging session with WindowsCE 6.0.

When I click 'Pause' I cannot see the program call stack.

Instead of a call stack with any functions of my program I just see a single address.

I am using [the debug technique described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (or [in German here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms228708%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Your "pause" likely stopped the application somewhere in a system call so there's no "line of code" to show.  Set an actual breakpoint in your code and run to that.  You'll then get a call stack and all of the other niceties of a debugging environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually looking for the call stack, not necessarily source code. I want to know in which API call my application currently is. The problem is that the application 'stops' running after two weeks and I want to know if it is stuck in an API call. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add logging.  Seriously, that's what you do at this point.  Hooking up KITL might show you where in the system calls you are as well, but that assumes you know at least with some degree of conviction where it is so you can put in the right debug symbols.  You don't want a full debug OS as that becomes info overload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know in which API call my application is when I click stop. Any other suggestions? I just want to know if the application currently is in a TCP connect receive or sleep or something like that.

Comment: So add logging for when you enter and leave those calls.

Comment: Or build a new version of the OS with debug versions of the network stack and coredll so you have PDBs.

Answer (score -2):

CE compiler does not support debug feature. You can debug in run time and with messageboxes unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any sources where I can read more information? Actually it supports debugging in general but there seems to be an issue when I click stop... I cannot see the call stack, instead just a single address.

Comment: Since when?  CE has supported debugging at least since the 2.12 days (when I started OS work).